# How to stop Ubuntu apt inside Docker forcing install of package version I don't want

Tags: r, docker, ubuntu, apt

In a Dockerfile that I'm using for building Ubuntu, I want the package `r-base`. The Ubuntu version is 22.04. I've also tried using older Ubuntu versions, 20.04 and 18.04, and I still get the newest version of `r-base`, 4.3.0, which I don't want. I want to avoid the latest version of R because a package I want to install to R is not available for the latest version of R. If I don't do anything, once the 22.04 Ubuntu image is built, I get R 4.3.3.

I used `apt list r-base` to see what versions of R are available.
That returned:

> r-base/jammy-cran40 4.3.0-1.2204.0 all
>
> r-base/jammy-cran40 4.2.3-1.2204.0 all
>
> r-base/jammy-cran40 4.2.2.20221110-1.2204.0 all
>
> r-base/jammy-cran40 4.2.2-1.2204.0 all
>
> r-base/jammy-cran40 4.2.1-3.2204.0 all
>
> r-base/jammy-cran40 4.2.1-2.2204.0 all
>
> r-base/jammy-cran40 4.2.1-1.2204.0 all
>
> r-base/jammy-cran40 4.2.0-1.2204.0 all
>
> r-base/jammy 4.1.2-1ubuntu2 all

Any of those would work, I think. I tried to use

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Install R and all the system dependencies necessary for gdalcubes package in R
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/'
# If previous line doesn't fall, try:
#RUN add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/'
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y wget tzdata
RUN wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu66_66.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i libicu66_66.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
**RUN apt install -yV r-base=4.2.2.20221110-1.2204.0**
```

in my Dockerfile. However, when I build the image, I get this error:

> => ERROR [10/15] RUN apt install -yV r-base=4.2.2.20221110-1.2204.0
> 1.5s
>
> ---
>
> > [10/15] RUN apt install -yV r-base=4.2.2.20221110-1.2204.0:
>
> ...
>
> #0 1.332  r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 4.2.2.20221110-1.2204.0) but 4.3.0-1.2204.0 is to be installed
>
> Dockerfile:15
>
> ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt install -yV
> r-base=4.2.2.20221110-1.2204.0" did not complete successfully: exit
> code: 100

I also tried.

`RUN apt install -yV r-base<4.3`

and

```
ARG R_VERSION=4.2.2-1.2204.0
RUN apt install -y r-base-core=${R_VERSION} r-base-html=${R_VERSION} r-doc-html=${R_VERSION} r-base-dev=${R_VERSION}
```

Both of which ended with same error.
I don't know why Ubuntu is trying to install a version of R that doesn't seem to be available to begin with in the first example (4.3.3) and ends up installing 4.3.0 when I explicitly say otherwise with other 2 attempts. How can I keep it from doing that and get the version I want instead?